# setWifiEnabled() throws java.lang.SecurityException for WRITE_SETTINGS permission

Tags: android-wifi

Why setWifiEnabled() throws setWifiEnabled for WRITE_SETTINGS permission (stack trace below)?

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider uri content://settings/system from pid=25173, uid=10148 requires android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1332)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1286)
at android.net.wifi.IWifiManager$Stub$Proxy.setWifiEnabled(IWifiManager.java:1156)
at android.net.wifi.WifiManager.setWifiEnabled(WifiManager.java:971)
```

This permission is not mentioned in Android documentation.
Should WRITE_SETTINGS permission be added to the manifest?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, setWifiEnabled() will write data to Android setting database, so it requires WRTITE_SETTINGS permission.